# How to publish a message in a callback function?

Tags: ros, callback, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello， I try my best to make my Issue clear：

main()

```
ros::NodeHandle node;
ros::Publisher pub_vt = node.advertise<ratslam_ros::ViewTemplate>(topic_root + "/LocalView/Template", 0);
ros::Subscriber sub = node.subscribe<uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid>("messageepc", 0, boost::bind(rfid_callback, _1, &pub_vt));
```

and,my clallback function is:

```
void rfid_callback( uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid rfid, ros::Publisher *pub_vt)
{
   do something;
}
```

And my error messages is:

```
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:313:34: error: could not convert ‘(& a)->boost::_bi::list1<A1>::operator[]<const boost::shared_ptr<const uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid_<std::allocator<void> > >&>(boost::_bi::storage1<boost::arg<I> >::a1_<1>)’ from ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid_<std::allocator<void> > >’ to ‘uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid_<std::allocator<void> >’
         unwrapper<F>::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_], a[base_type::a2_]);

and candidates are:

    In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp:42,
                 from /usr/include/boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp:23,
                 from /home/feixiao/catkin_ws/src/ratslam-ratslam_ros/src/utils/utils.h:32,
                 from /home/feixiao/catkin_ws/src/ratslam-ratslam_ros/src/main_lv.cpp:35:
    /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::_bi::list2<A1, A2>::operator()(boost::_bi::type<void>, F&, A&, int) [with F = void (*)(uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid_<std::allocator<void> >, ros::Publisher*); A = boost::_bi::list1<const boost::shared_ptr<const uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid_<std::allocator<void> > >&>; A1 = boost::arg<1>; A2 = boost::_bi::value<ros::Publisher*>]’:
    /usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:47:59:   required from ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()(const A1&) [with A1 = boost::shared_ptr<const uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid_<std::allocator<void> > >; R = void; F = void (*)(uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid_<std::allocator<void> >, ros::Publisher*); L = boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<ros::Publisher*> >; boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type = void]’
    /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:153:11:   required from ‘static void boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<FunctionObj, R, T0>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, T0) [with FunctionObj = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid_<std::allocator<void> >, ros::Publisher*), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<ros::Publisher*> > >; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid_<std::allocator<void> > >&]’
    /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:934:38:   required from ‘void boost::function1<R, T1>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid_<std::allocator<void> >, ros::Publisher*), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<ros::Publisher*> > >; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid_<std::allocator<void> > >&]’
    /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:7:   required from ‘boost::function1<R, T1>::function1(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<InputIterator>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid_<std::allocator<void> >, ros::Publisher*), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<ros::Publisher*> > >; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid_<std::allocator<void> > >&; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<InputIterator>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
    /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1069:16:   required from ‘boost::function<R(T0)>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<InputIterator>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid_<std::allocator<void> >, ros::Publisher*), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<ros::Publisher*> > >; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid_<std::allocator<void> > >&; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<InputIterator>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
    /home/feixiao/catkin_ws/src/ratslam-ratslam_ros/src/main_lv.cpp:142:119:   required from here
    /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:313:34: error: could not convert ‘(& a)->boost::_bi::list1<A1>::operator[]<const boost::shared_ptr<const uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid_<std::allocator<void> > >&>(boost::_bi::storage1<boost::arg<I> >::a1_<1>)’ from ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid_<std::allocator<void> > >’ to ‘uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid_<std::allocator<void> >’
         unwrapper<F>::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_], a[base_type::a2_]);
```

I have read some other people's problems like:
[this](http://answers.ros.org/question/63991/how-to-make-callback-function-called-by-several-subscriber/?answer=63998#post-id-63998)
and this [link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/12045/how-to-deliver-arguments-to-a-callback-function/)

but it don`t work.
can you give me some suggestion?

thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214386/how-to-publish-a-message-in-a-callback-function?/) by [feixiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/23311/feixiao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-07-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2015-07-23**:
Is that really your callback function? It would be nice to see it if not... And if that is your callback, then the compiler is trying to do function pointers and the function to which they are pointing isn't valid. Comment out the line and compile.

**Comment by [feixiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/23311/feixiao/) on 2015-07-28**:
thank you,i use a global variable and it works,although i don`t know why my BOOST::BIND is wrong yet.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2015-07-28**:
Wait... Why do you need to do a bind here?

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-29**:
Because he want(s/ed) to supply the publisher by the function call and in the function pointer. So making a double parameter function to a single parameter function by bind ... but actually when the publisher is global you do not need the bind anymore. Just supply the function name, remove pub param

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-29**:
One of my simplest nodes using a class, with directly publishing in the callback:
https://github.com/Hacks4ROS/h4r_joysound/blob/develop/src/joysound_node.cpp

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2015-07-29**:
That's what I figured. I don't use boost all that much. Pretty neat stuff.

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-30**:
Not when you're getting this errors... When I read them I am always like: WTF? :D

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2015-07-30**:
Hahaha, yup. That's a pretty good description of it... It's at the very least intimidating. XD

**Comment by [feixiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/23311/feixiao/) on 2015-08-02**:
haha, it's she:^)and you are sooo funny. i use it because i read someones code and he use it. but global var is a better way

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2015-08-02**:
Agreed! And our apologies! It's quite nice to have some women in this forum! Welcome aboard. :)

**Comment by [feixiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/23311/feixiao/) on 2015-08-02**:
O(∩_∩)O thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

pay attention to

```
/home/feixiao/catkin_ws/src/ratslam-ratslam_ros/src/main_lv.cpp:142:119:   required from here
    /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:313:34: error: could not convert ‘(& a)->boost::_bi::list1<A1>::operator[]<const boost::shared_ptr<const uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid_<std::allocator<void> > >&>(boost::_bi::storage1<boost::arg<I> >::a1_<1>)’ from ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid_<std::allocator<void> > >’ to ‘uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid_<std::allocator<void> >’
```

change your callback function to

```
void rfid_callback( const uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid::ConstPtr& rfid, ros::Publisher *pub_vt)
{
   do something;
}
```

when you declare your subscriber and publisher

```
ros::NodeHandle node;
ros::Publisher pub_vt = node.advertise<ratslam_ros::ViewTemplate>(topic_root + "/LocalView/Template", 0);
ros::Subscriber sub = node.subscribe<uhf_rfid_api::UhfRfid>("messageepc", 0, boost::bind(&rfid_callback, _1, &pub_vt));
```

---

Originally posted by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) with karma: 710 on 2016-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [feixiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/23311/feixiao/) on 2016-01-21**:
awesome!  I should add a const  before uhf_rfid_api, it works!!!thanks a lot

**Comment by [feixiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/23311/feixiao/) on 2016-01-25**:
ok,I knew why that I have to declare a const before my message datatype,the definition of the publisher advertise is:
Publisher advertise(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, bool latch = false)
and the callback is:
void Foo::callback(const std_msgs::Empty::ConstPtr& message)

**Comment by [feixiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/23311/feixiao/) on 2016-01-25**:
the definition of ConstPtr is
typedef boost::shared_ptr VoidConstPtr;
so ConstPtr  just a declare
right?

**Comment by [Arthur_Ace](https://answers.ros.org/users/39923/arthur_ace/) on 2019-02-26**:
Still relevant in 2019, thanks my man!

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2019-03-02**:
LOL, my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would either recommend you using a global publisher variable for simple nodes, or in a class doing the publisher with a member variable. In both of these ways you would not need that pointer to the publisher in the callback function header.

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-07-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1